# Using KDE - Application Menus Missing in Qt Apps

Tags: kde, qt, appmenu

I have multiple desktop environments installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, and am primarily using KDE (today).  Here's the problem I've noticed.

When I've been building some newer versions of Qt-based applications from their git repos, specifically Qt Creator and Tiled, everything builds fine.  However, when I run the compiled program, there are no application menus in their window.  I do not see this same problem when using older, pre-packaged debs for the same applications.

I've completely removed/tested/re-installed appmenu-qt to no avail.

I've checked the application config files, and find no MenuBar entries.  I even added/tested MenuBar=true and MenuBar=Enabled, with no change.  And, like I said, the prepackaged versions showed their menus - so this shouldn't be the problem anyway.

If I change the Application Appearance | Style | Fine Tuning settings for the Menubar style to be a Top screen menubar or Titlebar button menu, I can see and access the menu as expected.  When I change the setting back to "In application", the menus are gone again.

I have all the prerequisite Qt dev libraries installed, and received no errors or warnings when configuring/qmaking or compiling the apps.

Does anyone have any idea why the appmenus wouldn't be showing up in the application window?

Comment: Is this with Qt 4 or Qt 5? KDE is built with Qt 4 (unless you're using Plasma Next), some things in Qt 5 might not look like the things in Qt 4.

Comment: Qt 5.2.1.  I'm not sure what you mean by "might not look like".  The application menus don't display at all when I compile them myself, but they're displaying fine in the only slightly older pre-compiled .deb versions (which also use Qt 5.2.1).

Comment: The only way I've been able to work around this is to add `menuBar()->setNativeMenuBar(false);` to the code for the projects I've been compiling.  Unfortunately, that will make the menu _always_ show up in the application window, regardless of KDE settings.  Anyone have any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1307619. Another work-around is to unset QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME in your environment.

Comment: Please Don't add just a link to another website as your answer.  What if the website is down? What if it is permanently damaged? (crash+restore) 
Please enter a synopsis of the (in this case bug, otherwise solution) to your answer.  Please update your answer...
Hey, I'm a moderator now, but I started like you, *making the exact same mistake in my first answer*!  ;-)

Comment: I realize that you were very nice in your wording as a moderator, but that's a bug report at Ubuntu's upstream website (so Launchpad is *the* the canonical source), so this answer should be valid, at least with the workaround stated. (If anything, the reverse would be true - should Ubuntu link to Ask Ubuntu as the non-authoritative source? What if SO was down? OH NOES!) :)

Comment: Xfce4 (Xubuntu Trusty) has this problem with QtCreator, shame it still hasn't been fixed.